# SetWinEventHook with custom data

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using `SetWinEventHook` hook to detect the selection of Edit Controls. In the event hook callback function, is there a way to specify custom data? In my case the custom data would be the `VKeyboard` instance.

Please see the code for a better description of what I am trying to achieve.

```
class VKeyboard
{
public:
    static void CALLBACK winEventProc(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD  event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
    {
        // Somehow access VKeyboard instance?
        VKeyboard* keyboard = ??;

        IAccessible* pAcc = NULL;
        VARIANT varChild;
        HRESULT hr = AccessibleObjectFromEvent(hwnd, idObject, idChild, &pAcc, &varChild);

        if ((hr == S_OK) && (pAcc != NULL))
        {
            VARIANT varRole;
            hr = pAcc->get_accRole(varChild, &varRole);

            // if user selects a edit control: show window
            if ((hr == S_OK) && (varRole.vt == VT_I4) && (varRole.lVal == ROLE_SYSTEM_TEXT))
                ShowWindow(keyboard->mainHwnd, SW_SHOW);
            else ShowWindow(keyboard->mainHwnd, SW_HIDE);

            pAcc->Release();
        }
    }

    VKeyboard() 
    {
        SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, NULL, (WINEVENTPROC)&winEventProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);


        SetWindowLongPtr (mainHwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)this);
    }

    HWND mainHwnd;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your hook callback is implemented as an [Out of Context hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373611.aspx), it is always called in the context of the thread that calls `SetWinEventHook()`, even when hooking events of other processes.  As such, you can use [Thread Local Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686749.aspx), or even just a global variable, to store your `VKeyboard` object pointer. Provided you only need one instance of `VKeyboard`, that is.

```
class VKeyboard
{
private:
    HWINEVENTHOOK hHook;
    static VKeyboard *pKeyboard;

    static void CALLBACK winEventProc(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD  event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
    {
        IAccessible* pAcc = NULL;
        VARIANT varChild;
        HRESULT hr = AccessibleObjectFromEvent(hwnd, idObject, idChild, &pAcc, &varChild);

        if ((hr == S_OK) && (pAcc != NULL))
        {
            VARIANT varRole;
            hr = pAcc->get_accRole(varChild, &varRole);

            // if user selects a edit control: show window
            if ((hr == S_OK) && (varRole.vt == VT_I4) && (varRole.lVal == ROLE_SYSTEM_TEXT))
                ShowWindow(pKeyboard->mainHwnd, SW_SHOW);
            else ShowWindow(pKeyboard->mainHwnd, SW_HIDE);

            pAcc->Release();
        }
    }

    VKeyboard() 
    {
        hHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, NULL, &winEventProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);

        mainHwnd = ...;
        SetWindowLongPtr (mainHwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)this);
        pKeyboard = this;
    }

    ~VKeyboard()
    {
        UnhookWinEvent(hHook);
        pKeyboard = NULL;
    }

    HWND mainHwnd;
};
```