# How to pass context to a WinEventProc (callback for SetWinEventHook)?

Tags: c++, winapi, lambda, callback, function-pointers

The question is in the title: How can I have the callback for `SetWinEventHook` have some context information? Usually functions that take callbacks also take a context parameter they pass on to the callbacks, but not this one.

Using a global (including `thread_local`) variable as suggested in [SetWinEventHook with custom data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37095691/setwineventhook-with-custom-data) for example is almost certainly unacceptable.

There may be more than one caller to the utility function that sets the WinEvent hook to do something so global is out. `thread_local` *may* work, but it also may not. What if the callback calls the same utility function and sets yet another hook? They will both get called next time I pump messages. Using `thread_local` requires me to define a contract that forbids a single thread to set more than one WinEvent hook through me, and requires my callers to abide by it. That's a pretty arbitrary and artificial limitation and I prefer not to set it.

I'm reimplementing in C++ a little PoC I had in C#. There I could simple use capturing lambdas and they would convert to function pointers that I can pass via P/Invoke to `SetWinEventHook`. C++ unfortunately doesn't have that feature (probably because it requires allocating WX memory and dynamically generating a little code, which some platforms don't allow), but perhaps there is a platform-specific way to do this?

I seem to remember that ATL did something like that in the past, and I guess I can probably implement something like this too, but maybe there's a better way? If not, perhaps somebody has already written something like that?

(Another valid solution would be a clever-enough data structure and algorithm to solve the reentrancy problem.)

Comment: think that only way in this case allocate executable stub memory, where will be context pointer saved and call your `WinEventProc` from this stub already with context pointer. and pass to `SetWinEventHook` address of this stub. this require write some assembly code and have different versions for x86 and x64.

Comment: Only **non-capturing** lambdas can be used where function pointers are expected.  So, using a dynamically allocated proxy stub is about the only option remaining that suits your needs, but even that might not work due to your "*which some platforms don't allow*" restriction.  That is exactly what the proxy stub would have to do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, lets be precise: only non-capturing lambdas are *required* to have cast operators to function pointers. The standard mostly defines a minimum requirements. Implementation are free to add features, relax requirements, etc. (They're usually not allowed to make the requirements more stringent though.) A given implementation *could have* provided such cast operators in capturing lambdas. The standard does not forbid it, I'm almost certain. The platforms I was thinking of were stuff like Xbox 360 and Windows kernel-mode drivers. I'm not sure about the situation with DEP in user mode.

Comment: `I'm not sure about the situation with DEP in user mode` - we must allocate memory with `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` as result this will be work always. `The platforms I was thinking of were stuff like Xbox 360 and Windows kernel-mode drivers` - ?! how this related too windows user mode api ?

Comment: @RbMm: That's a great question. Let me remind you. In my question I mentioned *in passing* that in my opinion the likely reason C++ doesn't require all lambdas to be convertible to pointers to functions but only non-capturing lambdas is that there exist some platforms on which this is not possible. I **did not** say user-mode code on Windows is one of them. A very useful comment told me to use a dynamically allocate a "proxy stub" (a novel and impressing term in it own right) but warned me that what he tells me to do may actually not work because of allegedly my restriction on dynamically...

Comment: ... allocating executable memory. I replied to the honorable sir (who had already wrote a nonsensical answer and deleted it a few seconds later and also discovered America and the inability to simply cast capturing lambdas to pointer to functions in a now deleted comment) and said that these restricting platforms are rather unique and specialized environments like kernel-mode Windows drivers (where you don't have a kernel-mode equivalent of `VirtualProtect`, and while you may allocate executable memory from the non-paged pool, starting with Windows 8 you shouldn't if you want to get HCK/HLK...

Comment: ... certification). So you're right - this has nothing to do with my question as user-mode Windows is probably not one of those problematic environments on which this is impossible. Now if you would be so kind and let @RemyLebeau know that. Thank you. Seems like not only `WinEventProc`s have problems with keeping context.

Comment: @conio - and about context - let think. callback function signature not have this param. it simply not passed to function when it called. so from where we can get this context ?! only one way, if function pointer and will be this 'context'. so for every call we need pass **unique** function pointer, for "extract" context from it. i not familiar with lambda, but how i understand this is only static function with **constant** address. as result any  lambda can not be used for got context